# Handling multiple inputs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and was learning how to handle multiple inputs in form. Here is the code :

```
class Login extends Component {

  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange (evt) {
    // check it out: we get the evt.target.name (which will be either "email" or "password")
    // and use it to target the key on our `state` object with the same name, using bracket syntax
    this.setState({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <form>

        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" onChange={this.handleChange} />

        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" onChange={this.handleChange} />

      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

The question is how can this.setState({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value }); replace several handlers? Does [evt.target.name] represent both inputs?

Comment: what do you mean `How can it replace several handlers?`

Comment: Either add individual event listener on each form field or use id or name on form field and conditionally extract value from event target in your callback using that id.

Comment: `this.setState( { [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value })` in here `[evt.target.name]` turnes into `email` or `password` depending which one initiated a call.

Comment: There is a glaring title in react docs "Handling Multiple Inputs" https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs. You cant learn react without reading docs. Also a simple search would solve your problem.

Comment: @EdwardChopuryan, ok, why we want [evt.target.name] to be turned into either email or password. How [evt.target.name] can solve the issue of multiple change handlers? I mean don't we need both email and password

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`[evt.target.name]` doesn't necessarily represent both inputs, it merely takes the name of the event's target and makes it the key for `setState`.

This means that when the `email` form changes, the `this.setState` will act as follows:

```
this.setState({ email: evt.target.value });
```

For the `password` this works the same;

```
this.setState({ password: evt.target.value });
```

So it doesn't necessarily replace several handlers, it mostly replaces them and supplies a shorter way to handle the event. (Think DNRY (Do Not Repeat Yourself)).

However many fields you have in the form, `this.setState({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value });` will behave as explained above.

To further elaborate, in your current form, with a field for the `email` and a field for the `password`, the following will happen;

```
handleChange (evt) {
    this.setState({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value });
}
```

Above function will take the event's target and extract the `name` and `value` attributes. So for *EACH* input with this change handler it'll change the function to i.e. the following if the `email` gets changed;

```
handleChange (evt) {
    this.setState({ email: "email@domain.com" });
}
```

OR i.e. for the `password`

```
handleChange (evt) {
    this.setState({ password: "superstrongpassword" });
}
```

OR i.e. for the `name`

```
handleChange (evt) {
    this.setState({ name: "John Doe" });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you Mike for your kind answer, what I get so far is [evt.target.name] turns into either email or password. But what is the point of getting the value of one input since we need both email and password to be added into state. I hope you get my point

Comment: That's the thing, both values will get added into the state since they both have the same change handler function, the function takes the name of the element that's targeted as well as the value and sets that to the state. The `[evt.target.name]` usage limits the change handlers to just one for your form

Comment: can I imagine it like this, [evt.target.name] targets that input which gets changed, I mean, if we type 123 into password input it will get changed. And if we type mail@mail.com then email gets targeted. I mean, [evt.target.name] for all inputs having name and that targeted only when we type something. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, you could see it something like that, please see the edit in my post, that may explain the situation more

Comment: thanks Mike a lot for your kind help and explanation:).

Comment: Not a problem at all @Dickens

Answer (score 9):

This works because `evt` is a [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event), `evt.target` is the changed DOM element and `evt.target.name` is the value of the `name` attribute of that element.

This means that when you change one of the `<input>` elements the `handleChange` function is called and the state's `email` or `password` (the names of those two inputs) property is changed to the changed element's value.

`{[variable]: value}` is just the syntax you use when you want to use a string as a property name in an object literal.

Answer (score 9):

This is basic example.

```
class Login extends Component {

  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange (evt, field) {
    // check it out: we get the evt.target.name (which will be either "email" or "password")
    // and use it to target the key on our `state` object with the same name, using bracket syntax
    this.setState({ [field]: evt.target.value });
  }

  render () {
    return (
  <form>

    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" onChange={(event)=>this.handleChange(event, "email")} />

    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" onChange={(event)=>this.handleChange(event, "password")} />

  </form>
);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Every input has a name attribute which is used to reference elements in JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted. Here you are using `name` and `password` as names.

```
this.setState({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value })
```

This is using ***ES6 Computed property names***.
`evt.target.name` takes the name of the input (i.e the `evt.target`) to which the handler is attached and being called and sets it as the key for your state. So, essentialy each time you change something in the input, your state corresponding to that input's name changes as well.

Keep one thing in mind. You need to keep the **initial state** names and the names of your input **consistent** with each other for this to work.

You can always write seperate handlers but that just convolutes the codebase and are essentially doing the same thing. So it is just following the **DRY** methodology. Might as well use this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi Hemant, ok we use this.setState({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value }) to achieve DRY in our code. But look, [evt.target.name] turns into either email or password. If [evt.target.name] turns into, say, email then how about password. How can we reference both inputs by having this.setState({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value }) in which  [evt.target.name] turns into email

Comment: @Dickens Although the handler is same for both the inputs, the value in state  will only be updated for the input that is being changed at the time. If you change email, email state will be updated and similarly for password. Each state is independent of each other. They just only share the method/code of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

for create a state for this, is necessary create a object with any property and set

> just behaivor on component an above class with your scheme class and component this is trigger for you response

1. Create an object property

   ```
   state = {
    nameForProperty: '',
    anotherNamenameForProperty: ''
   }
   ```
2. create an event for setState a pass event for function callback
   onHandleEvent = e => {

   ```
           this.setState ({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
           })
              console.log(this.setState)

          };
   ```
3. Call function from input

   ```
     <form>
     <input name="namenameForProperty" onChange={this.onHandleEvent} value={this.state.} />
     </form>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
    handleChange (evt) {
      let name = evt.target.name
      this.setState({ [name ]: evt.target.value });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can also adopt chained arrow function handleChange as `handleChange = key => e => { ... }` , then use it in input as `onChange={this.handleChange('mail')}`.

```js
constructor(ops) {
  super(ops)
  this.state={
    prompt: '',
    form: {
      name: '',
      mail: '',
      message: ''
    }
  }
}

handleChange = key => e => {
  let newForm = {
    ...this.state.form,
    [key]: e.target.value
  }
  this.setState({
    form: newForm
  })
}
```

```
render() {
  let { name, mail, message } = this.state.form
  return (
    <form action="#">
      <input type="text" value={name} onChange={this.handleChange('name')} className="form-control" placeholder="Name*" />
      <input type="email" value={mail} onChange={this.handleChange('mail')} className="form-control" placeholder="E-mail*" />
      <textarea value={message} onChange={this.handleChange('message')} className="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </form>
  )
}
```